# Is there a way to convert an object dataframe to float on python 2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-2.6

I have a dataframe cointaining objects . I want to convert my object column to a float I used :

```
fdk['Child | Nominal weight'] = dfk['Child | Nominal weight'].astype(float)
```

But i get an error like

> ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 4,5

I also tried to used `pd_tonumeric()` but it returns only int value the float value are converted to `Nan`

Can anyone know how to do it please ?

Comment: Start by moving to Python 3.

Comment: haha ! i can't for now ! thanks